# Swift If statement with Optionals (from calculator Stanford/Youtube)

Tags: swift, youtube

Logic walk-through question with if statement and optionals in Swift.

A zero gets deleted in the calculator label and I'm not following why that happens.

Around 1:10:03 in the Stanford youtube video here: https://youtu.be/_IRx1zoriPo?t=1h10m3s .

code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // linked to label
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInMiddleOfTyping = false

    // linked to keys 0-9
    @IBAction func touchDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let isDigit = sender.currentTitle!

        if userIsInMiddleOfTyping {
            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
            display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + isDigit
        } else {
            display.text = isDigit
        }
        // user now typing
        userIsInMiddleOfTyping = true

    }

}
```

Initially the program runs and the zero default set in the label is in the display.  The userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping is false so the else block runs and displays the zero in the calculator.  It's then set to true.

Second time through it then is true and whatever was pressed is now in the display.  What was pressed is then concatenated to whatever is in the display.

So what happened such that the display now replaces the zero?  How did the initial value get replaced instead of being concatenated?

I'm not looking for different code here, it's just an arbitrary example.  Any help appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it by talking it through.  Initially the bool is false so the else block is hit on the initial key press, and the display of zero is replaced by whatever key was pressed.  The bool is then set to true.  All subsequent presses are then true and are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

touchDigit is an action. It does not run unless one of the buttons are pressed

> Initially the program runs and the zero default set in the label is in the display

Correct

> The userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping is false so the else block runs

Incorrect. The method does not run because no buttons have been pressed